# npm uninstall - g create-react-app checkPermissions error

Tags: reactjs

I am new to reactjs, and I'm trying to create a reactjs app, and I follow the steps on react web, and it shows error. My node version is v12.19.0 and my npx version is 6.14.8

when I try `npx create-react-app ac-web` I get this message in my terminal

```
hazeleroy@Hazels-MacBook-Pro acweb % npx create-react-app ac-web

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.0, which is behind the latest release (4.0.1).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

I go to the website and it's telling me to use `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

I get this message

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/balanced-match
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/ansi-regex
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/builtins
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/at-least-node
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/chardet
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/color-name
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/ansi-styles
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/commander
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/cli-width
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/concat-map
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/color-convert
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/brace-expansion
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/core-util-is
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/emoji-regex
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/envinfo
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/escape-string-regexp
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/figures
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/fs.realpath
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/graceful-fs
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/has-flag
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/inherits
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/block-stream
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/is-fullwidth-code-point
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/isexe
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/lodash
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/mimic-fn
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/isarray
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/minimatch
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/minimist
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/mkdirp
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/ms
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/onetime
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/debug
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/mute-stream
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/external-editor/node_modules/tmp
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/os-tmpdir
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/path-is-absolute
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/path-key
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/process-nextick-args
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/run-async
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/safe-buffer
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/safer-buffer
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/iconv-lite
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/external-editor
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/semver
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/shebang-command
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/shebang-regex
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/signal-exit
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/restore-cursor
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/cli-cursor
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/string_decoder
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/readable-stream
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/duplexer2
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/strip-ansi
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/string-width
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/chalk
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/supports-color
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/string_decoder
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/isarray
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/through
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/tslib
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/rxjs
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/type-fest
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/inquirer
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/uid-number
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/ansi-escapes
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/universalify
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/jsonfile
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/fs-extra
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/util-deprecate
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules/readable-stream
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/validate-npm-package-name
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/which
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/cross-spawn
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/wrappy
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/once
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/inflight
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/glob
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/rimraf
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/fstream
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/tar
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/fstream-ignore
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/tmp/node_modules/rimraf
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/tmp
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/xtend
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/tar-pack
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/through2
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/hyperquest
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/external-editor/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/tar-pack/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/through2/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/tmp/node_modules
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/buffer-from
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/buffer-from'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/buffer-from'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/buffer-from'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/hazeleroy/.npm/_logs/2021-01-16T16_48_50_102Z-debug.log
hazeleroy@Hazels-MacBook-Pro acweb %
```

Thanks,